# Can I reuse database file of localdb in Express editions

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012-express, sql-server-2012-localdb

I am going to build a small application and like to use SQL Server LocalDB, but I'm confused about some points

When I start my instance and shared it in main PC and connecting to my database, does anyone on my local network can see this instance?

- if yes, so he can connect to it?
- if yes, what is if I closed my application, does the instance still run until he going to end work?
- if no way to solve this way

I think to work LocalDB instance until face case to work multiple user in network to switch this database from LocalDB to normal Express edition and work with it as normal.

So can I use the `*.mdf, *.ldf` files of LocalDB in SQL Server Express edition any time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *When I start my instance and shared it in main PC and connecting to my database, does anyone on my local network can see this instance?*

No - `LocalDB` is a **local machine ONLY** affair - only from your own local machine can you see and connect to that instance.

> *So can I use the `*.mdf, *.ldf` files of LocalDB in SQL Server Express edition any time?*

**Yes, absolutely** - those `.mdf` (and `.ndf` and `.ldf`) files are compatible between `LocalDB` (which is really just a variant of SQL Server **Express**) and any other full-fledged SQL Server version (Express, Web, Standard, Developer, Enterprise) - just not with SQL Server Compact - that's a totally separate world with `.sdf` files.